# Download dependency from SourceForge

Tags: gradle

I have a project that depends on [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/). The artifacts on Maven central are quite outdated, so I would like to download them directly from SF. But I don't know how to do that with gradle.

More specifically, what I try to achieve is:

1. Download the distribution .zip from SF.
2. Unpack the distribution and extract the .jar (with a rename so that the .jar file name contains the version) and the two .dlls.
3. Add the extracted .jar to the compile configuration.
4. The tests have a runtime dependency on the .dlls.
5. The final project .jar should include both the jacob.jar and the .dlls.

This is a quite open-ended question, and I think I know how to do some of the points on the list. Task 2 is probably just a copy task, and task 5 is just about telling gradle what goes into the jar. Task 1 seems like something that should be easy, but I don't think that the copy task accepts a URL as source.

What I really don't know how to do, is task 3. How can I add a derived resource to a configuration, and make it trigger a task if it is absent? It is like normal dependency resolution, but where the included dependency is derived from another, transformed, dependency.

I realize that the easy way out is to just include the Jacob dependencies in my project, but I really don't like to pollute my SCM repositories with binary artifacts :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For step 1, you'll have to write your own download task (should be easy with Groovy). Step 3 can already be done in the configuration phase, provided you know the path to the unzipped Jar beforehand. So you'll just add a regular file dependency. You are right about step 2 and 5. Step 4 will probably configure the `test` task (e.g. perhaps you'll have to set a system property for the native code location). What remains is to establish the necessary task dependencies.